# Regular expression for translating quoting syntax to HTML

Tags: javascript, regex, quoting

I have a quote syntax for my users, similar to SO:

```
So, Mike, you say:

>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
>Nam mi dui, porta non gravida id
>sodales venenatis tellus

But this makes no sense!
```

There can also be a multiple quotes. I need to translate this into HTML markup like this, using JavaScript:

```
So, Mike, you say:

<div class="quote">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Nam mi dui, porta non gravida id
    sodales venenatis tellus
</div>

But this makes no sense!
```

Here is the best that I came up with, but it implements HTML to every line, not the block of lines.

```
x = x.replace(/^&(amp;)?gt;([^\n]+)$/mg, "<div class=\"quote\"> $2 </div>");
```

Is it possible to write such a regular expression? If yes, what would it look like?

Comment: Please argument on the downvote.

Comment: Why downvoted this ?

Comment: You might want to pick up a MarkDown parser and use it. For example, PageDown, as used by StackOverflow to render the preview in real time on client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is trying to manipulate HTML with a regular expression. (I say that based on the fact you're searching for HTML entities for `>` rather than literally for `>`.) That is almost always a bad idea, *nearly* as bad as trying to parse HTML with just a regular expression. [Obligatory Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/157247).

You cannot do this with a single `replace` call. But to my surprise, you can do it with two, or with a single *outer* call that uses a function callback to make a bunch of inner calls.

Here's the two-call version:

```
x = x.replace(/^(?:(?:>|&gt;|&amp;gt;).*?[\r\n]+)+/gm, '<div class="quote">***$&</div>');
x = x.replace(/(?:\*\*\*|^)(?:>|&gt;|&amp;gt;)/gm, '');
```

The first finds repeated serieses of lines with the quote markers and wraps the div markup around them. (I included a raw `>` in the set, so it looks for `>`, `&gt;`, and `&amp;gt;` [see note below about that last one, though].) The second removes the quote markers. You can't remove them in the first `replace` because you're replacing the entire group of lines. Also note that I had to prefix the first marker, since once we've added the div markup, it's not at the beginning of a line anymore.

Here's the one-call-with-subcalls version:

```
x = x.replace(/^(?:(?:>|&gt;|&amp;gt;).*?[\r\n]+)+/gm, function(m) {
  return '<div class="quote">' + m.replace(/^(?:>|&gt;|&amp;gt;)/gm, '') + '</div>';
});
```

How robust are they? Probably not very, see the first paragraph of the answer above. :-)

Side note: Your regex seems to be looking for `&amp;gt;` as a quote marker. I've preserved that above, but if you have `&amp;gt;` in your HTML, you have *double-encoded* HTML, which is usually an indicator of a problem elsewhere.

**Live Example of the two-calls version** with variations for the various different quote markers:

```js
function test(x) {
  snippet.log("Before:");
  snippet.log(x);
  x = processString(x);
  snippet.log("After:");
  snippet.log(x);
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));
}

function processString(x) {
  x = x.replace(/^(?:(?:>|&gt;|&amp;gt;).*?[\r\n]+)+/gm, '<div class="quote">***$&</div>');
  x = x.replace(/(?:\*\*\*|^)(?:>|&gt;|&amp;gt;)/gm, '');
  return x;
}

test(
  "So, Mike, you say:\n" +
  "\n" +
  ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\n" +
  "&amp;gt;Nam mi dui, porta non gravida id\n" +
  "&gt;sodales venenatis tellus\n" +
  "\n" +
  "But this makes no sense!\n"
);
test(
  "So, Mike, you say:\n" +
  "\n" +
  "&amp;gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\n" +
  ">Nam mi dui, porta non gravida id\n" +
  "&gt;sodales venenatis tellus\n" +
  "\n" +
  "But this makes no sense!\n"
);
test(
  "So, Mike, you say:\n" +
  "\n" +
  "&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\n" +
  "&amp;gt;Nam mi dui, porta non gravida id\n" +
  ">sodales venenatis tellus\n" +
  "\n" +
  "But this makes no sense!\n"
);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

**Live Example of the one-call-with-subcalls version**:

```js
function test(x) {
  snippet.log("Before:");
  snippet.log(x);
  x = processString(x);
  snippet.log("After:");
  snippet.log(x);
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));
}

function processString(x) {
  x = x.replace(/^(?:(?:>|&gt;|&amp;gt;).*?[\r\n]+)+/gm, function(m) {
    return '<div class="quote">' + m.replace(/^(?:>|&gt;|&amp;gt;)/gm, '') + '</div>';
  });
  return x;
}

test(
  "So, Mike, you say:\n" +
  "\n" +
  ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\n" +
  "&amp;gt;Nam mi dui, porta non gravida id\n" +
  "&gt;sodales venenatis tellus\n" +
  "\n" +
  "But this makes no sense!\n"
);
test(
  "So, Mike, you say:\n" +
  "\n" +
  "&amp;gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\n" +
  ">Nam mi dui, porta non gravida id\n" +
  "&gt;sodales venenatis tellus\n" +
  "\n" +
  "But this makes no sense!\n"
);
test(
  "So, Mike, you say:\n" +
  "\n" +
  "&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\n" +
  "&amp;gt;Nam mi dui, porta non gravida id\n" +
  ">sodales venenatis tellus\n" +
  "\n" +
  "But this makes no sense!\n"
);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Be careful with `[\r\n]+` since it may match more than one newline, in this case the contiguity of lines starting with `>` will be broken.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: In HTML, a *series* of whitespace is just one bit of whitespace. (Based on what the OP posted, apparently they've already at least partially converted the original text to HTML.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it can be done: match all the block and then inside a callback function,  split it and remove the initial `>` and wrap in `div`:

```js
var s = 'So, Mike, you say:\n\n>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\n>Nam mi dui, porta non gravida id\n>sodales venenatis tellus\n\nBut this makes no sense!';
var res = s.replace(/^(?:(?:>|&(?:amp;)?gt;)[^\n]+)+/gm, function(m, grp1, grp2, offset, input) {
     return m.split("\n").map(function(el) {
         return '<div class="quote">' + el.replace(/(?:>|&(?:amp;)?gt;)/g,'') + "</div>";
     }).join("\n");
});
alert(res);
```